# How do I make this conversion function work in both directions?

Tags: javascript, html, input, converters

I'm new in JS and I have trouble to finish a converter only with inputs, I explain the problem !
We have two input, Meters and Feet. when I transmit a number to Feet I have the result in Meters. And I Want to do the same think with Meters . and vice versa

```js
let metresEl = document.getElementById('inputMetres');


function LengthConverter(valNum) {
    metresEl.value = valNum/3.2808;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input type="number" id="inputFeet" placeholder="Feet" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Metres</label>
      <input type="number" id="inputMetres" placeholder="Metres">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've seen better. I'd recommend you read about how to create a [mcve]. There was far too much irrelevant details in your original question. I've edited these out to show how you could ask the same question with much less code (**minimal**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another parameter in the `LengthConvertor` function which will say the input unit (meter or feet) and convert it accordingly inside the function using `if`.

```
function LengthConverter(valNum, inputUnit) {
   if(inputUnit === 'feet')
    metresEl.value = valNum/3.2808;
   if(inputUnit === 'meter')
    feetsEL.value = valNum * 3.2808;
}


<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input type="number" id="inputFeet" placeholder="Feet" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value,"feet")" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value,"feet")" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Metres</label>
      <input type="number" id="inputMetres" placeholder="Metres" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value,"meter")" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value,"meter")" >
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i think use second parameter like ID's it's very powerful, if I have multiples inputs, I choose this option. it's better than having a lot of functions. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Added inverse conversion:

```js
let metresEl = document.getElementById('inputMetres');
let feetEl = document.getElementById('inputFeet');


function FeetToMetres(valNum) {
    metresEl.value = valNum/3.2808;
}

function MetresToFeet(valNum) {
    feetEl.value = 3.2808*valNum;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input type="number" id="inputFeet" placeholder="Feet" oninput="FeetToMetres(this.value)" onchange="FeetToMetres(this.value)" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Metres</label>
      <input type="number" id="inputMetres" placeholder="Metres" oninput="MetresToFeet(this.value)" onchange="MetresToFeet(this.value)">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer your code works perfectly, and very clear.

Comment: @Furax if you want to say thank you then please upvote the post

Answer (score -1):

You can add a `element.addEvenetListener` to each input, and when it chances you get it's value, convert, and put in on the right input.

```js
let metresEl = document.getElementById('inputMetres');
let feetsEl = document.getElementById('inputFeets');

metresEl.addEventListener('change', yourCode);
feetsEl.addEventListener('change', yourCode);
```

For exemple, if metres input changes, you convert to feets and add to feets input.

Comment: hello thank you for your answer, but the code does not work ! `metresEl.addEventListener('change', valNum => metresEl.value = valNum/3.2808);

feetsEl.addEventListener('change', valNum => feetsEl.value = valNum*3.2808);`   I did that but I got nothing